# Can I create a IVR Using Sinch

Tags: sinch

I am trying to an app in Sinch which would act like an automated voice response menu where people could choose from a set of options and then the application could forward the call accordingly.  I know Twillio has this, but I wanted to use Sinch for various reasons.

The documentation is not very complete, but it does give an IVR type example which suggests that it "might" be possible.

```
{
"Instructions": 
[{
    "name" : "PlayFiles",
    "ids" : [ "welcome" ], 
    "locale" : "en-US"
}],
"Action": 
{
    "name" : "ConnectPSTN",
    "number" : "+46555000111",          
    "maxDuration" : 600,
    "locale" : "en-US",
    "cli" : "+46555000222",
    "suppressCallbacks" : true
}
```

}

but there isn't a  verb (like Twillio) which can capture this response.

Has anyone out there been able to create a simple IVR using sinch?

Answer (score 0):

Edit, we do support this now

Please look at https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#runmenuaction